# Has some queries in Python

Tags: application-development, python

Has some queries in Python

1) Is Python language is easy or difficult

2) What are the tools required for the Python programming

Comment: This has nothing to do with askUbuntu. But NO Python to me is one of the easiest languages. Imagination is the best tool to have ;)

Comment: Some useful resources for learning Python are mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/84255/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Python is considerd as a easy language. But it is dependance on on your interest and coding style

2) the python shell and text editor are installed by default in ubuntu,  if you want quickly create ubuntu application, you can try [quickly [image: Install quickly]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quickly)

Terminal installation:

```
sudo apt-get install quickly
```

Comment: Don't be misled by the "it's easy" that professional programmers might bestow upon the language. Good programming is hard, no matter what language you use. In fact, I'd say it's harder to do in Python, simply because Python is very lenient in nature, and makes it very easy to do things bad/wrong. Also, when programmers say "it's easy" they generally mean it's easy for other programmers to pick up very quickly. People who don't think in the same way as programmer, will still probably find things fairly difficult.

Comment: @dobey:agreed, but AFAIK python is the best language to start coding